# move bar freezes when continous events are fired while moving

Tags: c#, user-controls, repaint

I have a UserControl. I can move a bar.

Every time the bar is moved, an event is firing. When i don't subscribe anything to the event everything is fine. When i move the bar, the bar is drawed at the right position.

But when i subscribe something, the paint method of the control seems too slow. My bar don't move but my event is firing. When you stop moving the bar, it is painted at the right position again.

How can i solve this freezing bar problem? Like fire only after the draw? I tried to call the event at the end of the OnPaint-method but that don't fixed the problem.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Bitmap btm = new Bitmap(_drawRectangle.Width, _drawRectangle.Height);
  using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(btm))
  {
    ... //draw bar, etc.
  }
  this.drawbox.Image = btm;

  base.OnPaint(e);

  //if (PositionChanged != null) PositionChanged(...);
}
```

It is not a problem when the event is not fired every move. It can be also every new draw of the bar.

Comment: You should investigate which operation inside the event handler causes the slowdown. What's in there? Is that okay if you do that operation only every x milliseconds, instead of every time the move event is fired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paint is a low priority operation, it will only occur when nothing else needs to be done.  So the problem is not that your OnPaint() method is slow, it is the "subscribe something" code you wrote.  If it is slow enough then there might yet be another MouseMove notification waiting to be processed when the "something" code completes.  Which causes it to run again.  So no more painting occurs and the UI looks "frozen" until you stop moving the mouse.

You can probably fix the problem by calling this.Update() in whatever event you use.  That forces OnPaint() to run.  That trade-off will probably be noticeable, the "bar" will move more jerky.  You'll have to write more efficient code to make it smooth again.

Notable is that your bitmap painting code looks quite bad, assigning the Image property of a PictureBox causes *another* paint event fire.  Get ahead by drawing straight to e.Graphics instead so this picture box isn't needed at all.  Set this.DoubleBuffered = true in the constructor to suppress flicker.

Comment: Without using the second Graphics, it is working without any problems. Thank you.